# Zustand not updating state in other files (NextJS)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, zustand

I have two files, the first like so:

```
export const progressQ = create((set) => ({
  progress: 0,
  setProgress: ($progress) => set(() => ({ progress: $progress })),
}));  
  
export default function parentComponent() {
  const $progress = progressQ((state) => state.progress);
  // ...

  function Overlay() {
    return (
      <span>{$progress}</span>
    )
  }

  // ...

  return (
    <>
      // other components
      <Overlay />
    </>
  )
}
```

The second file contains a main function which is called from the parentComponent when a button is clicked. The function is like so:

```
export async function work($input) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // some logic ...
    for (...) {
      // some more logic ...
      // declare $progress variable
      progressQ.setState({ progress: $progress * 100 });
      if (endCheck) {
        resolve(someResult)
      } else {
        // logic ...
      }
    }
  })
}
```

**The problem** is that when the state is changed, it is immediately updated within the function and can be checked, such as by alerting the value after every change. **But**, the state within the first file, where it should be rendered, does not change until the function has completed, meaning that the value is 0, then immediately 100 after the function has completed, instead of updating every time it is changed from within the function. Even using useEffect to alert the value every time it changes only triggers at 0 or 100.

(Yes I know I am not even using the setProgress method declared within the Zustand)